# Resizing size of Circle for circle class in Python and "circle object has no attribute "canvas""

Tags: python, class, geometry, resize

1. My results showed "circle object has no attribute 'canvas'" Is there any way that I can solve it? My results showed "circle object has no attribute 'canvas'" Is there any way that I can solve it? thank you.

```
class EnlargeShrinkCircle:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, r):
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.r = r
        
    def enlargeCircle(self, r):            
        self.r += r
        
c1 = circle( 4, 5, 1)
        
c1_rdelta = 3        

if c1.r == 1:
    c1.r += 2
    c1.canvas.create_oval(
                     0.5 - self.r, 0.5 - self.r,
                     0.5 + self.r, 0.5 + self.r )

print(c1.x0, c1.y0, c1.r)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10552/2081812378.py in <module>
     14 if c1.r == 1:
     15     c1.r += 2
---> 16     c1.canvas.create_oval(
     17                      0.5 - self.r, 0.5 - self.r,
     18                      0.5 + self.r, 0.5 + self.r )

AttributeError: 'circle' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

Comment: You cannot use `self` outside your class. Instead you must create an instance of your class on which you can call its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no variable called `self` outside the definition of your class. When you create the circle object `c1` it becomes what you were referring to as `self` inside the class. `self` basically refers to an object of the class. So you would call your methods and properties like `c1.r`

```
c1 = circle( 4, 5, 1)
        
c1_rdelta = 3        

if c1.r == 1:
    c1.r += 2
    c1.canvas.create_oval(
                     0.5 - self.r, 0.5 - self.r,
                     0.5 + self.r, 0.5 + self.r )

print(c1.x0, c1.y0, c1.r)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Sandil. But I still have a built problem with the "c1.canvas.create_oval(" --> AttributeError: 'circle' object has no attribute 'canvas'. Is there anyway that I can fix this?

Comment: You can only call `canvas` on an object that knows this method/variable and your `circle` class doesn't know it. You probably need `tkinter` to use `canvas` if you want to draw it.

Comment: as mentioned in the above comment, you need to define any method or property on your class from which you create an object to call it from the object. Where did the method canvas come from? If you are looking at code from some tutorial you need to make sure you are using the same libraries and extending their classes properly.